# why is entropy maximum at equilibrium for a closed system?

Tags: entropy

I don't understand why entropy is maximum at equilibrium for a closed system:(
I tried understanding some of the answers her on chemistry StackExchange but they involved the use of probabilistic functions and stuff and I find them difficult to understand.

SO can anyone explain this in simpler terms as I am a high school student:)

Comment: Can you explain, in your words, what entropy is?

Comment: Do you mean "isolated system"? Whose entropy are you maximizing? That of the system or that of the universe?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_system

Comment: @Zhe i keep two ideas in mind :1.measure of disorder,2:Distribution of energy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that an ideal gas is held in a flask connected at another evacuated flask with a tap and let this whole arrangement be isolated. The system is at equilibrium and no heat will enter or leave. Naturally, the gas completely fills this first flask. Now open the tap and the gas escapes into the second flask but does no work as it expands into a vacuum. Again the system comes to equilibrium but the entropy has increased because the gas occupies a bigger volume. The entropy cannot increase any more as the gas fills the whole volume instead of only part of it. We conclude therefore that entropy is at a maximum at equilibrium. Experience shows us that the gas does not spontaneously go back into the first flask, which would reduce the entropy, the chance of this happening is so incredibly small it has never been observed.

Notes: The reason that the entropy increases with volume increase is that there are more ways of arranging molecules (i.e. more positions) in a bigger volume than in a smaller one. Work is $p\Delta V$ so if the external pressure $p=0$ no work is done.

Comment: always at equilibrium.